# How to autosize the "auto group column"?

Tags: ag-grid

How to auto resize all columns, including the [auto group column](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#auto-column-group) ?

The following code only resizes standard columns and not the auto group column as `this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()` doesn't return the auto group column :

```
autoSizeAllColumns() {
  const allColumnIds = this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().map(c => c.colId)
  this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds)
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to size and autosize the autogroup column directly  by using the colID (which I learned is 'ag-Grid-AutoColumn').

To size it specifically:

```
onGridReady:function(params)
{
    params.columnApi.setColumnWidth('ag-Grid-AutoColumn', 250);
}
```

To autosize:

```
onFirstDataRendered:function(params)
{
    params.columnApi.autoSizeColumn('ag-Grid-AutoColumn');
}
```

Comment: By looking into how stored state works. We allow users to save their views, so when writing to the DB, `gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState()`, I noticed that was the autogroup column ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to auto-size all columns (including pivot and group columns), then you need to use `getAllGridColumns()`.

Here is what it looks like in React (with added code for ignoring any columns that have the supressSizeToFit property set):

```js
function gridReady(params) {
  gridApi.current = params.api;
  columnApi.current = params.columnApi;
}

function autoSizeAll() {
  const colApi = columnApi.current;
  colApi.autoSizeColumns(
    colApi.getAllGridColumns().filter(column => !column.colDef.suppressSizeToFit),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your own autocolumn:

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    autoGroupColumnDef:{
        headerName:' autogroup',
        cellRendererParams:{
            suppressCount: true,
            checkbox:true
        }
    };
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#configuring-auto-column

From the documentation:

> Allows specifying the group 'auto column' if you are not happy with
>   the default. If grouping, **this column def is included as the first
>   column definition in the grid**. If not grouping, this column is not
>   included.

Comment: Even with its own definition, `this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()` does not return this column so we can't autosize it with `this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds)`.

Comment: `gridColumnApi.getAllGridColumns()` will include the auto-group columns as well as any other aggregate columns. But odly, setting the `colId` property on the `autoGroupColumnDef` does not result in you being able to retrieve the auto column by the new name. You **have** to use *ag-Grid-AutoColumn*